Issue while logging MDC values with Jetty 12
We have a service A that initiates an API call to another service B. In response service B transfers zip file in chunk to service A. We have written a custom response listener which transfer chunk from service A to its client without storing it in buffer.
while doing so when ever connection is aborted from client of service A, key-value pair which we are inserting into MDC map are getting cleared out and we are unable to log those key-value.
for example
MDC.put(ABORTED, "true") is not printed in log
Jetty version(s)
Jetty 12.0.8
Jetty Environment
core
Java version/vendor (use: java -version)
Amazon Corretto 17.0.9
OS type/version
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
logback-access version
2.0.2
class RapidResponseListener(
    val response: Response?,
    val callback: Callback?,
    val mdc: MutableMap<String, String>
) : org.eclipse.jetty.client.Response.Listener {

    companion object {
        val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RapidResponseListener::class.java)
    }

    var aborted = false

    override fun onContent(clientResponse: org.eclipse.jetty.client.Response?, content: ByteBuffer?) {
        try {
            content?.let { c ->
                val array = ByteArray(c.remaining()).apply { c.get(this) }
                Content.Sink.asOutputStream(response).write(array)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            aborted = true
        }
    }

    override fun onComplete(result: org.eclipse.jetty.client.Result?) {
        if (!aborted) {
            log.debug("${result?.response}")
            try {
                log.debug("Data written")
            } finally {
                MDC.setContextMap(mdc)
                MDC.put(MDC_TS_RESPONSE_COMPLETE, System.currentTimeMillis().toString())
                log.debug("Succeed")
                callback?.succeeded()
            }
        } else {
            MDC.setContextMap(mdc)
            MDC.put(ABORTED, "true")
            log.debug("aborted")
        }
    }
}

import ch.qos.logback.access.common.spi.IAccessEvent
import ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import org.slf4j.MDC


const val MDC_TS_REQUEST_DISPATCHED = "MDC_TS_REQUEST_DISPATCHED"
const val MDC_TS_RESPONSE_COMPLETE = "MDC_TS_RESPONSE_COMPLETE"
const val UUID = "UUID"
const val ABORTED = "ABORTED"

data class AccessRecordBuilder(
    @JsonProperty("uuid") var uuid: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("ht-met") var httpMethod: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("ht-url") var requestUrl: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("ht-sta") var httpStatusCode: Int? = null,
    @JsonProperty("tim-elp") var timeElapsed: Long? = null,
    @JsonProperty("abrt") var aborted: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("tim-rqr") var timeRequestDispatched: String? = null,
    @JsonProperty("tim-rcp") var timeResponseComplete: String? = null
)


class AccessJsonLayout : LayoutBase<IAccessEvent>() {

    override fun doLayout(event: IAccessEvent?): String =
            event?.let {
                val record = AccessRecordBuilder()
                val mdcMap: Map<String, String>? = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()
                mdcMap?.get(MDC_TS_REQUEST_DISPATCHED)?.let { record.timeRequestDispatched = it }
                mdcMap?.get(MDC_TS_RESPONSE_COMPLETE)?.let { record.timeResponseComplete = it }
                mdcMap?.get(UUID)?.let { record.uuid = it }
                mdcMap?.get(ABORTED)?.let { record.aborted = it }
                record.timeElapsed = event.elapsedTime
                record.httpStatusCode = event.statusCode
                record.httpMethod = event.method
                Mapper.mapperSlash.writeValueAsString(record) + "\n"
            } ?: (Mapper.mapperSlash.writeValueAsString(mapOf("logerr" to "empty event")) + "\n")
}

